# I misspelled "use strict" to "use stricr"

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, misspelling

this code gives error which makes perfectly sense

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
usestricr
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but this doesn't why

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
"usestricr"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

please help i'am noob in this

Comment: The first one gives you an error since you're accessing an undeclared variable. The second one doesn't give an error since you're **not** accessing an undeclared variable. You're creating a string then doing nothing with it. It's useless but valid JavaScript code. Why would it give an error?

Comment: "You're creating a string then doing nothing with it" oh! ok thanks VLAZ :)

Answer (score 1):

So that triggering strict mode in JS engines that support it wouldn’t cause errors to be thrown in older engines, the code to trigger it is **just a string**.

Putting a *different* string there is still **just a string** which is still syntactically valid even if semantically nonsense.

Comment: you guys are really awesome, i got my answer in less than 15 min